# Gibbs phenomenon/ behabiour at discontinuities for general eigenfunction expansions

Tags: fourier-series, eigenfunctions, continuity

I was wondering if there is a generalisation of the Gibbs phenomenon, and the value or general behaviour of a function expansion, in a general orthonormal, complete basis?

Answer (score 2):

Gibb's phenomenon is a *curse* for all approximation schemes based on orthogonal functions. In [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250891872_The_Gibbs_phenomenon_for_series_of_orthogonal_polynomials), it is studied for the classical orthogonal polynomials.